# N.V. Meaning in Jazz

Tags: jazz, saxophone, trombone

I play in a big band.

One arrangement we play has "N.V." In quite a lot of the parts. Particularly in trombone and saxophone parts.

Any ideas what it might mean?

[image: N.V.]

Comment: @happyhacker the piece dramatically changes its feel at this point. It goes from swing to straight with everyone playing crotchets.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The "N.V" just means No Vibrato.